# Ubuntu 22.04 USB not booting + multiple resets needed for OS to load

Tags: boot, system-installation, 22.04

HW: HP Envy x360 Ryzen 5 2500U, Radeon Vega

When I create a USB iso and try to load it, it gets stuck at the loader about 95% of time. Just the splash screen circle spinning around.

I once managed to get to the wall of text, and it seems to be stuck at an amdgpu parameter of some sorts.

I tried disabling secureboot, but to no avail.

Sometimes it enters the installer, and you can install the system. On the first reboot it starts normally, but then whenever you reboot it, it gets stuck again even when installed. I than have to restart it 7-10 times before it enters the installed system.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you verify the integrity of the written medium? And did you do a checksum on the .iso?

Comment: @JoepieEs yes, of course. I'm not the only one reporting the same issue on HP Envy x360

Comment: Update UEFI before anything else. Secure Boot is immaterial because you won't be using proprietary drivers. Also you can try booting with the safe graphics (or compatibility mode) option.

Comment: @ChanganAuto it does not work, unfortunately.